# How to overflow numbers and dates in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I've noticed that, unlike text, dates and numbers don't overflow (even if Text Wrapping is set to "overflow"):

[image]

A workaround is to select them and go to Format > Plain text, but that changes the values to actual text.

Another workaround is to merge them with the adjacent cells.

So is there a way to input "2021-04-21", format it as long date (Wednesday, April 21) and have that overflow while keeping the original input and not merging it with additional cells?

Comment: I don't think so, other than merging it with the cell to the right, and I'm not offering that as an answer.

Comment: I guess this is intended behavior: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/25869880. You could request this feature via `Send feedback` (on the editor, click `Help > Help Sheets improve`).

Answer (score 2):

as the commenters said, no. there's no way to do that as it's the intended behavior.  BUT! I've encountered and wanted to do something similar before and here's the workaround I used.

Presumably, the reason you want to keep them as 'numbers' instead of 'text' is because the dates are used in some other formula downstream.  So the solution i used is to just go ahead and format that column as plain text (as you mentioned) to achieve the desired "overflow", but *change the formulas that refer* to that cell.  instead of referring to cell A2 for example, your formula could refer to 1*A2.  That 1* will "force" the text back into a number for the purposes of whatever downstream calculation you're doing.  If it's a whole range, then you can use 1*A2:A.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set a cell with the date.
2. Refer to that cell with the formula `=TEXT(*ENTER-CELL-REF*,"DDDD, dd mmmm")`

For example, in column A enter all your dates (which you hide or set the text to the same colour as the background). Then in Cell B1 enter `=ArrayFormula(TEXT(A1:A,"DDDD, dd MMMM"))`.